# Two entities with common one-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I have the following scenario in my project and I'm starting to get with a few questions about it.

On the `User` class, querying `QuestionFollows` directly will be better (in terms of performance) than querying `Questions` and then `QuestionFollows`?

Another question ... is the relationship between `User` and `QuestionFollow` necessary/redudant?

**Domain**

```
public class User
{
    public long   UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name   { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Question>       Questions       { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionFollow> QuestionFollows { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public long   QuestionID  { get; set; }
    public long   UserID      { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User   User        { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionFollow> QuestionFollows { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionFollow
{
    public long     QuestionFollowID { get; set; }
    public long     QuestionID       { get; set; }
    public long     UserID           { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date             { get; set; }
    public Question Question         { get; set; }
    public User     User             { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Querying QuestionFollows on user will not give you the same rows as querying Question then QuestionFollows. QuestionFollows on User is like `User.Questions.SelectMany(x => x.QuestionFollows)`. In this case, QuestionFollows directly on User has better performance than the select many option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you're doing seems right based on assumptions I gather from your code: a user has questions and can also follow questions that belong to other users. If that's correct, then it seems you're simply struggling with how these relationships play out.

From `User`, querying `Questions` will return all questions belonging to that `User` instance. Querying `QuestionFollows`, however, will return all questions that `User` has chosen to follow, *whether or not those questions belong to that `User` instance*. In other words, these are two functionally different datasets, so it's not about which is more performant; it's about which returns the data you actually need.

The relationship between `User` and `QuestionFollows` is also not redundant, because again you're tracking a fundamentally different facet of the relationship. In `QuestionFollow` the `User` is the entity that is *following* the question and the `Question` is the entity that is being followed. That `Question` entity could have a completely different `User` attached to it, as that `User` entity is the one who *owns* the question.